# AlertDialog with ArrayAdapter for a dinamic ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog

I want to generate an AlertDialog that contains a ListView.
Searching, I found that the better way to do this, is with ArrayAdapter.

I try on entire Web and it just doesn't work. The following code don't do some significantly stuff, because I don't know how to proceed.

**I have to update the listView or the adapter? Where?**

Here is the method that I call when the button is pressed (ps. using onButtonClick(View view)).

```
private void showAlertDialog()
{
    ListView listView = new ListView(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
    arrayAdapter.add("a");
    arrayAdapter.add("b");
    arrayAdapter.add("c");

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item clicked at index " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Here I call a method to update listView? 
        }
    });

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("My Dialog");

    dialogBuilder.setView(listView);

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null); // TODO
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); // nothing simply dismiss

    AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.show();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need create a custom layout for your AlertDialog

```
dialog.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

-Create custom alert dialog like this

```
public void createCustomDialog(Context context, String title) {
        View dialogView = View.inflate(context,R.layout.dialog, null);
        ListView lv= (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"}));
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                        .setTitle(title)
                                        .setView(dialogView)
                                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                // TODO do something
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                //TODO do something
                                            }
                                        });
        builder.create().show();

    }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Maybe I didn't define the problem very well... I need to alter the data of the list when I click on an Item.

Comment: what's data do you want to alter?

Comment: The "a", "b" and  "c".

Answer (score 0):

You have to make custom Dialog class.

Like this.

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

    private ListView listView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_dialog);
      listView=findViewById(R.id.listview);


    }
}
```

In onCreate method,you can put new layout which has a listview.

And you can make listview contents as you did in Question.